# How to create a Icosahedron that behaves as one

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I'm trying to create a d20 (a dice with 20 sides or icosahedron).
So far, I've been doing it like this:

```typescript
const IcosahedronDice = (props) => {
  const [ref] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: [0, 10, 0] }));
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 2, 0]} castShadow receiveShadow>
      <icosahedronBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 0]}/>
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="#802d2d" />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

The issue with that is that I'm using "useBox", which collides on my plane (code below) and behaves like a box should, even tough my object still looks like a icosahedron as ref, it rolls and rotates like a box, but as soon as I try using "useConvexPolyhedron" (which I guess is the right ref for a icosahedron), my icosahedron goes right trough the floor (my plane) without collision.

**Plane:**

```typescript
const Plane = () => {
  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({ rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0] }));
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 0, 0]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} receiveShadow>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="#49687a" />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

I tried finding a solution on the docs, but so far, nada! Not sure if I'm missing something or the docs are actually too confusing.

Edit:
**The whole code**:

```typescript
import './App.css';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, Stars, Icosahedron } from '@react-three/drei';
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { Physics, useBox, usePlane, useConvexPolyhedron } from '@react-three/cannon';

const IcosahedronDice = (props) => {
  const icosahedron = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(4)
  
  const [ref] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: [0, 10, 0] })); // THIS should be useConvexPolyhedron
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 2, 0]} castShadow receiveShadow>
      <icosahedronBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[1, 0]}/>
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="#802d2d" />
    </mesh>
  )
}

const Plane = () => {
  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({ rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0] }));
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 0, 0]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} receiveShadow>
      <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100, 100]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="#49687a" />
    </mesh>
  )
}
const DiceCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Stars />
      <OrbitControls />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <spotLight
        position={[10, 10, 10]}
        intensity={0.5}
        penumbra={1}
        castShadow
      />
      <Physics>
      <IcosahedronDice position={[0, 0, 4]} rotation={[0, 1, 0]}/>
        <Plane />
      </Physics>
    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default DiceCanvas;
```

Comment: Where in the Cannon.js docs are you seeing this option?

Comment: Pretty much everything I did was scouting trough the internet, not the docs for the most part, but... github.com/pmndrs/use-cannon

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this demo](https://cannon.pmnd.rs/#/demo/ConvexPolyhedron) is the one that most closely applies to your situation. You can see [the source code here](https://github.com/pmndrs/use-cannon/blob/master/examples/src/demos/ConvexPolyhedron.tsx). Unfortunately I can't help you further because I can't see the rest of your code, but I'm sure you'll find the answer in the source-code since the diamonds and cones behave exactly as you described the icosahedron.

Comment: I'm not sure as I still need to take a closer look at the source code, but I don't think that's what I need, since my object has 20 sides... I'll let you know as soon as I'm able to open my project later on!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! It did not work as expected, my object is still going trough the ground

Answer (score 0):

I've actually also struggled a bit with finding the resources to get a [Rhombicubeoctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) (26th sided die) to work. My use case might be a little different to yours, since I'm importing a GLTF for my shape, but I'm sure you can extract the necessary bits for it.

```
const D26 = (props) => {
  // I'm importing my shape here.
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/beveled_die.glb'); 
  // Memoizing the calculations for the `Cube` object geometry (Even if it says cube, it's a 26 sided polyhedron.
  const geo = useMemo(() => toConvexProps(nodes.Cube.geometry), [nodes]); 
  // Getting the reference from the `useConvexPolyhedron` hook. Notice how I'm passing in the goe object.            
  const [ref, api] = useConvexPolyhedron(() => ({ mass: 1, ...props, args: geo }));
```

I'm passing in the geo memoized object to the args of the `ConvexPolyhedron`. The function `toConvexProps` is the following:

```
const toConvexProps = (bufferGeometry) => {
  const geo = new Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(bufferGeometry);
  // Merge duplicate vertices resulting from glTF export.
  // Cannon assumes contiguous, closed meshes to work
  geo.mergeVertices();
  return [geo.vertices.map((v) => [v.x, v.y, v.z]), geo.faces.map((f) => [f.a, f.b, f.c]), []]; // prettier-ignore
};
```

Here's the `D26` jsx:

```
<group
  ref={ref} // This is the ref we obtained from the useConvexPolyhedron
  onClick={(e) => {
  ...
  {...props}
  dispose={null}
>
  <mesh
    castShadow
    material-color="#1e293b"
    receiveShadow
    geometry={nodes.Cube.geometry} // These are the geometries from the GLTF object loaded.
    material={materials.Material}
  />
  ...
</group>
```

At the same time, here's my `Canvas` jsx:

```
<Canvas gl={{ alpha: false }} camera={{ position: [0, -12, 16], zoom: 3 }}>
  <hemisphereLight intensity={0.35} />
  <spotLight position={[30, 0, 30]} angle={1} penumbra={1} intensity={1} castShadow />
  <Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Physics gravity={[0, 0, -30]}>
      <Plane color={'#334155'} />
      <Rhombicuboctahedron position={[4, -4, 0]} />
    </Physics>
  </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

The `Plane` objects you're using are the same as the ones as I'm using, so that should be fine.

Sorry for the lenghty answer lol. Hope that this will help you resolve your issue!